# How to move the cursor from MDTextField to MDRoundFlatIconButton by pressing "Tab" key on your keyboard?

Tags: python, tabs, kivymd, text-cursor

I'd like to use a keyboard to move the cursor among input text fields for getting input and also move the same cursor onto MDRoundFlatIconButtons to execute functions.

I have figured out to move cursor among MDTextFields but the same cursor does not move to buttons when i keep pressing "Tab" key on my keyboard.

In the program, if you press "tab" key on your keyboard, the curse moves only among MDTextFields.

Python file

```
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.config import Config                
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '600')         
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '750')        

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.factory import Factory
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kaki.app import App
from kivy.factory import Factory
import os

from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable

from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.metrics import dp


Builder.load_file('new_window_mo.kv')

class Dex(Popup):

    ptName = ObjectProperty(None)
    ptAdminWeight = ObjectProperty(None)
    ptIdealWeight = ObjectProperty(None)


    def on_open(self):
        
        self.ptName.focus = True
        self.data_tables = None

    def calculate(self):
        ptName = self.ptName.text
        ptAdminWeight = self.ptAdminWeight.text
        ptIdealWeight = self.ptIdealWeight.text

        self.data_tables = MDDataTable(
            size_hint=(0.9, 0.8),
            column_data=[
                ("No.", dp(30)),
                ("User", dp(30)),
                ("Password", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                (
                    "1",
                    "The pitonist",
                    "Strong password",
                ),
                (
                    "2",
                    "The c++ lover",
                    "Save me!!!:)",
                ),
            ]
        )
        self.ids.data_layout.add_widget(self.data_tables)

    def print(self):
        ptName = self.ptName.text
        ptAdminWeight = self.ptAdminWeight.text
        ptIdealWeight = self.ptIdealWeight.text

        printme(self, ptName, ptAdminWeight, ptIdealWeight)

    def clear(self):
        self.ptName.text =""
        self.ptAdminWeight.text =""
        self.ptIdealWeight.text = ""
    

    
class Remi(Popup):
    def build(self):
        
        return self.root

class test1(Popup):
    def build(self):
        
        return self.root

class MyLayout(Widget):
    pass
class AwesomeApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return MyLayout()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

Kevy file

```
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory

<Dex>:
    ptName : ptName
    ptAdminWeight : ptAdminWeight
    ptIdealWeight : ptIdealWeight


    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1
    #pos_hint: {"x":0.2, "top":0.9}

    title: "Dex - Weight-Based"   

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (1,0,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size

    MDGridLayout:  #전체 블록 1칼럼 4row

        adaptive_height: True
        md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
        md_bd_color: app.theme_cls.accent_palette
        cols: 1
        rows: 4
        size: root.width, root.height
        size_hint:1,1

        MDBoxLayout:   #첫 번째 약 이름
            adaptive_height: True
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            size_hint: 1, .4
            orientation: "vertical"
            padding: dp(0), dp(30), dp(0), dp(10)
            spacing: dp(20)
            MDLabel:
                text:"Dex"
                halign: "center"
                font_size: '45sp'
            MDLabel:
                text:"Pre"
                halign: "center"
                font_size: '30sp'
        #환자이름,몸무게 정보 넣기
        MDGridLayout:
            rows: 3
            adaptive_height: True
            size_hint:1, None
            height: self.minimum_height
            #spacing: dp(15)
            padding: dp(50), dp(10), dp(50), dp(20)

            MDTextField:
                id: ptName
                #input_filter: "str"
                hint_text: "Patient Name"
                line_color_focus: 0,0,0,1
                font_size: '30sp'
                focus: True
                write_tab: False
                
            MDTextField:
                id:ptAdminWeight
                input_filter: "float"
                hint_text: "Admission Weight"
                required: True
                font_size: '30sp'
                line_color_focus: 0.9,0.75,0,1
                write_tab: False
            MDTextField:
                id:ptIdealWeight
                input_filter: "float"
                hint_text: "Idea Weight"
                required: True
                font_size: '30sp'
                line_color_focus: 0.9,0.75,0,1
                write_tab: False
        MDGridLayout:    #buttons
            cols: 4
            rows: 1
    
            size_hint: 1, .25
            pos_hint: 1, None
            pos_hint: {'center_y':0.5}

            padding: "20dp", "0dp", "20dp", "15dp"
            spacing: "20dp"

            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                text: "Calculate"
                icon: "calculator"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                font_size: '20sp'
                size_hint: .3, 1
                #theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 1,1,1,1
                icon_color: 1,1,1,1
                line_color: 1,1,1,1
                line_width: 2
                on_release: root.calculate()
                write_tab: False

            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                text: "Print"
                icon: "printer"
                pos_hint: {"center_y": .5}
                font_size: '20sp'
                size_hint: .3, 1
                #theme_text_color: "Custom"
                text_color: 1,1,1,1
                icon_color: 1,1,1,1
                line_color: 1,1,1,1
                line_width: 2
                write_tab: False
                on_release: root.print()

            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                text: "New"
                icon: "close-thick"
                font_size: '20sp'
                size_hint: .3, 1
                pos_hint: {'center_y': 0.5}
                text_color: 1,1,1,1
                icon_color: 1,1,1,1
                line_color: 1,1,1,1
                line_width: 2
                on_release: root.clear()
        BoxLayout:
            id: data_layout
            canvas:
                Color:
                    rgba: [1,1,.1,.6]
                Rectangle:
                    pos:self.pos
                    size:self.size
            

<Remi>:
    auto_dismiss: False
    size_hint: 1, 1

    title: "Remi Weight-Based "   
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0,1,0,1)
        Rectangle:
            pos:self.pos
            size:self.size
    
    BoxLayout:
        
        orientation: "vertical"
        size:root.width, root.height

        Label:
            text: "label 1" 
        Button:
            text: "Close"
            font_size: 24
            on_release: root.dismiss()
<MyLayout>
    BoxLayout:
        orientation:"vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height

        Button:
            id: data_scr
            text: "Dex"
            font_size: 32
            on_press: Factory.Dex().open()
        Button:
            text: "Remi"
            font_size: 32
            on_press: Factory.Remi().open()
```

Comment: Though not a good idea, however you can create a new instance of the last `MDTextField` and overwrite it's `keyboard_on_key_down` method.

Comment: Thank you. I haven't tried "keyboard_on_key_down" yet. I will try it over the weekend and then i will let you know.